# Run a script after some command were executed

Tags: command-line, shell-script, terminal

I have a list of scripts

- `./myscript <param> | grep "asd"`
- `./myotherscript <param> <param> > file`
- ...

How can I automaticaly run another script when one of these command in the list is executed and finished?

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you're trying to do. What/who runs these commands you have? Another script?

Comment: user run a script from command line

Comment: Oh. Why don't you put that command at the end of your scripts?

Comment: Because I don't want this... I want to create a list of script/commands wich will triger the execution of this script... is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to run both scripts, and run a third script when the first of the two finishes? Or run a third script twice, when the first script finishes and then when the second script finishes? Or do you mean to run one of these two scripts, and you want to say “and after than run yet another script”? Your question is still very unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to automatically execute something after a specific command:

### function

Create a function named after your specific command and execute the specific command afterwards. This is in my opinion the simplest and cleanest solution.

```
function myotherscript() {
   command myotherscript "$@"
   other_command_to_be_executed
}
```

### zsh

With zsh you can create a `precmd` function which will be executed before the prompt. This allows you to execute arbitrary other commands but you'll have to determine the executed command yourself.

```
function precmd() {
   last_cmd=$(history -1 |  sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//g")
   case "$last_cmd" in
   *myscript*) other_command;;
   *myotherscript*) other_other_command;;
   esac
}
```

### bash

Bash has the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable allowing you to implement your own `precmd` function. To use it you have to set it to a command which will be executed before the prompt:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND};bash_precmd"

function bash_precmd() {
  last_command=$(history 1 | sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//g")
  case "$last_command"  in
  *pattern*) command ;;
  esac
}
```

If you are using bash and want to use something like `preexec` or `precmd` have a look at [precmd and preexec with bash](http://www.twistedmatrix.com/users/glyph/preexec.bash.txt)

Comment: your "bash" solution worked for me... but I replaced "${PROMPT_COMMAND};bash_precmd" with "bash_precmd"... Thanks!